Implement Sink trait for AsyncWrite and a String
I want to implement the Sink trait for something that is AsyncWrite in order to send \n-separated strings.
Essentially I would like to implement the Sink version of tokio-stream LinesStream wrapper.
There are 4 methods to implement.
For poll_ready I assume we are always ready to send. For poll_flush and poll_close I call the inner methods.
For the start_send method I would like to call the inner write_all method, but it's asynchronous, so I'm not sure what method I'm supposed to use.
Any help would be greatly appreciated! While I can find a lot of info on the Stream side, the Sink one seems to be relatively neglected by the community.
use futures_util::Sink;
use pin_project_lite::pin_project;
use std::io;
use std::pin::Pin;
use std::task::{Context, Poll};
use tokio::io::{
    duplex, AsyncBufReadExt, AsyncRead, AsyncWrite, AsyncWriteExt, BufReader, BufStream, Lines,
};

pin_project! {
    #[derive(Debug)]
    pub struct LinesStream<R> {
        #[pin]
        inner: Lines<BufStream<R>>,
    }
}

impl<R: AsyncWrite + Unpin> Sink<String> for LinesStream<R> {
    type Error = io::Error;

    fn poll_ready(self: Pin<&mut Self>, _cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Result<(), Self::Error>> {
        Poll::Ready(Ok(()))
    }

    fn start_send(mut self: Pin<&mut Self>, item: String) -> Result<(), Self::Error> {
        let this = self.as_mut().project();
        let writer = this.inner.get_mut().get_mut();

        /* unclear how I can call the inner writer write */
        Ok(())
    }

    fn poll_flush(mut self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Result<(), Self::Error>> {
        let this = self.as_mut().project();
        let mut pinned = std::pin::pin!(this.inner.get_mut().get_mut());
        pinned.as_mut().poll_flush(cx)
    }

    fn poll_close(mut self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>) -> Poll<Result<(), Self::Error>> {
        let this = self.as_mut().project();
        let mut pinned = std::pin::pin!(this.inner.get_mut().get_mut());
        pinned.as_mut().poll_shutdown(cx)
    }
}

